# How to manage uploaded file in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-views

i want to manage(move and rename)files that user upload :

my upload form(html):

```
<form action="../valid_upload/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %} 
   {{form.as_p}}
   <input type="submit" name="send" value="send" />
</form>
```

my form(django part):

```
class UploadImageForm(forms.Form):
image = forms.FileField()
name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
about = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
taq1 = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
taq2 = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
taq3 = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

url.py(just a one line):

```
url(r'valid_upload/', views.valid_upload, name='valid_upload'),
```

and view.py(just a part of that):

```
if 'username' in request.session:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'image' in request.FILES:
            form = UploadImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                # Here goes the documentation code
            return HttpResponse(request.FILES['image'].content_type)
            //here i want to rename and move uploaded files
        else:
            return redirect('/upload_image')
    else:
        return redirect('/login/')
```

**i want to know how to rename uploaded file and move them on my directories.if you can help me :)**

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the request data to your form, and let the form manage your needs. Here is an example:

```
if 'username' in request.session:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'image' in request.FILES:
            form = UploadImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                # Here goes the documentation code
            return HttpResponse(request.FILES['image'].content_type)
            //here i want to rename and move uploaded files
        else:
            return redirect('/upload_image')
    else:
        return redirect('/login/')
```

You can use a django model too.
Here is the documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: what is UploadFileForm?

Comment: I'm showing you the documentation example. that's why i paste the link.

Comment: Tnx i will test it soon